# Facebook Fan page content not showing in page followers news feed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

my code is

```
        $page_id              = '***********';
        $access_token         = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/' . $page_id, array('fields' => 'access_token')))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        $page_access_token    = $access_token['access_token'];
        $data['link']         = "http://www.phpgang.com/";
        $data['message']      = "You can change it";
        $data['picture']      = "http://www.phpgang.com/wp-content/themes/PHPGang_v2/img/logo.png";
        $data['caption']      = "";
        $data['description']  = "you can change it";
        $data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
        $post_url             = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . '/feed';
        $ch                   = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFI ELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

If I post http://www.phpgang.com/ it is showing on followers news feed . But if I share any other link it is not showing in my news feed ...

any idea why it is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm that decides if someone shows up for followers/fans or not, you can´t really force it. As long as there is no error and the post shows up on the Page, there´s nothing else you can do. It will most likely show up for some followers, usually for those who interact with your Page a lot.